# how to use Melt function to rearrange a given data

Tags: r, melt

I am trying to use the following function here http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-two-plots-of-principal-component-analysis/

what I do is as follow:

```
data(iris) 
df <- iris[,1:4]
variable.groups <- c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50), rep(3,50))
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
pca <- prcomp(df, scale=TRUE)
melted <- cbind(variable.groups, melt(pca$rotation[,1:4]))
```

I get an error saying

```
Error in data.frame (..., check.names=FALSE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 150, 16
```

what I basically dont understand, is the melting in the above link, is there any idea, how i can set the iris data the same ?

Comment: `length(melt(pca$rotation[,1:4]))` is 16 and `length(variable.groups)` is 150. In the post you link, the length of both vectors are a match. `melt` basically transforms a wide data.frame into a long data.frame

Comment: @scoa that is true but do you have any idea how to fix variable.groups to be able to melt it ? how did I generate the variable.groups was based on different species and I thought that is the porpose of the example mentioned above . kinda confused now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

`variable.groups` needs to be of length 4. So this fixes it:

```
variable.groups <- c(1,2,3,4) #or any other 4 classes
```

**Long answer:**

Comparing your code with the code at http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-two-plots-of-principal-component-analysis/ i think you are mixing `sample.groups` and `variable.groups` up.

Taking `data` from there article it has the following dimensions:

```
> dim(data)
[1] 50 70
```

So `sample.groups` and `variable.groups` do have the following length:

```
> length(sample.groups)
[1] 50
> length(variable.groups)
[1] 70
```

In your code `df` and `variable.group` do have the following dimensions:

```
> dim(df)
[1] 150   4
> length(variable.groups)
[1] 150
```

So compared to the code you are referencing your `variable.groups` should have length 4.